# Simulate a Windows Docker setup in a VM

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm developing a command line (in Golang) which interacts with Docker. It works fine on Linux & Mac, although I have a bug when I try to make it work with Windows 10, but I don't have a Windows 10 laptop available.

What are my solutions ? I've tried the nested virtualization, but Hyper-v (which is used by Docker Desktop) is not able to start in my Windows virtual machine (created with VirtualBox which obviously doesn't support thise use case).

The Cloud providers don't seem to support this use case either, I'm kind of stucked.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229900/running-docker-in-windows-virtual-machine